# PostgreSQL - Automate schema and table creation - powershell

Tags: sql, postgresql, powershell, automation

I am trying to automate the creation of schemas and some tables into that newly created schema. I am trying to write a script in powershell to help me achieve the same. I have been able to create the schema, however, I cannot create the tables into that schema.

I am passing the new schema to be created as a variable to powershell.

script so far (based off the solution from the following answer. [StackOverFlow Solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/postgresql-executing-ddl-on-every-schema)):

---

```
$MySchema=$args[0]

$CreateSchema = 'CREATE SCHEMA \"'+$MySchema+'\"; set schema '''+$MySchema+''';'
write-host $CreateSchema
C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe -h $DBSERVER -U $DBUSER -d $DBName -w -c $CreateSchema

# To create tables
C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe -h $DBSERVER -U $DBUSER -d $DBName -w -f 'E:\automation\scripts\create-tables.sql' -v schema=$MySchema
```

At the execution, I see the following error:

```
psql:E:/automation/scripts/create-tables.sql:11: ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
```

The content of create-tables.sql is:

```
SET search_path TO :schema;

CREATE TABLE testing (
  id SERIAL,
  QueryDate varchar(255) NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got this in your first step:

```
$CreateSchema = 'CREATE SCHEMA \"'+$MySchema+'\"; set schema '''+$MySchema+''';'
```

Take out that `set schema` - it's erroneous and causing the schema not to be created. Then on the next step you wind up with an empty search path (because the schema never got created), which is why you get that error.

Comment: I removed the `set schema` code. Still, the same error persists. `psql:E:/automation/scripts/create-tables.sql:11: ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in`

Comment: Anything else which I can do to get this working? To me, it seems to be a trivial thing but, i cannot seem to find a quick solution, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to go through step by step. First comment out the second call to psql, run your script, then check manually that the schema exists. If so, comment out the first call to psql, run your script, and check if the testing table exists in the schema. You might also want to look through the database log files, and possibly set "log_statement = all" in your configuration file to see everything that actually gets run.

Comment: My code so far creates a schema and fails with the error when I am trying to create the tables. Since this is something which HI will be running only once per client, I am not worrying too much about checking if the schema exists (atleast not for now).

Comment: If the error you get when trying to create your tables is that "no schema has been selected to create in" then you should be checking if the schema exists.

Comment: the schema which is created by the script does exist. The error says: `psql:E:/automation/scripts/create-tables.sql:11: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in` which I believe is saying that no schema has been qualified to the table structure... Since I am trying to run this queries on different schemas, I want to keep it as dynamic as possible

Comment: But you've implicitly qualified the schema in which to create the table with the "set search_path" line. This progression, for instance, generates your error: "create schema test; set search_path = test; drop schema test; create table x (y int);". It's definitely relevant checking that your schema exists before trying to create tables in it.